# Can't connect (RDP) to Amazon EC2 instance after making changes to allowed cipher suites

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, cipher

In an attempt to get a better SSL Labs rating on an Amazon EC2 instance, I made changes to the allowed Cipher Suites on my Windows Server 2012 R2 EC2 Instance.  After making the change, I rebooted the instance, and I can no longer access the instance via remote desktop.  Obviously something I changed has made it so I can no longer connect to my server.  I had spent several hours configuring the instance.  I did not create an backup or AMI or anything before making the changes.

Am I completely out of luck here, and I do I have to terminate the instance, and start a new one, and spend several hours configuring it again, or is there a way to recover what I have done and gain access back to the EC2 instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying the Cipher suites, I accidentally disallowed RDP connections to my EC2 instance, and there is no way to gain access via RDP to that instance as a result.  I had to terminate the instance, and create a new EC2 instance from scratch and set it up how I needed it.  Let this be a lesson, if you are making any system changes to an EC2 instance, to create an snapshot, or an AMI backup before making the change, in case that change results in being locked out of the instance.